# AppointmentItem.EntryId not set intermittently?

Tags: c#, outlook-addin

In an Outlook addin, in the region close event:

```
private void AppointmentItem_Close(ref bool Cancel){}
```

I have the following code:

```
task.FindItemOrNew<StringDataItem>(ProviderItemNames.ItemId).Value = _appointmentDetails.AppointmentItem.EntryID;
```

The stuff on the left is just about setting a property on an object which sends an XML message to another server.  If I hard code the right hand side, it works 100% everytime.

The issue I have is that intermittently, `AppointmentItem.EntryId` is apparently not populated.  For any given user, it will work 99 times then fail.  I have added some logging to demonstrate that the problem is on the right hand side of the assignment and it surely is.

Before I start trying to kludge round this, e.g. some sort of spin loop until it does have a value (I suspect it might be a timing issue), does anyone have any ideas what might be causing this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try to call AppointmentItem.Save first.

Comment: Thank you for the tip.  Makes sense.  This is in a deployed application so I will need to wait to see if the support calls stop.  I will be sure to come back and let you know.  Thanks again.